# Specify comma as decimal separator in all outputs (SAS 9.4)

Tags: sas, decimal-point, output-formatting

My data has '.' as decimal separator, but that's not the problem for me.

[image]

I want all outputs in SAS to use comma as decimal separator, and use dot as 3-digit separator, but I don't find a global option to do that.

I'm doing a PROC LOGISTIC and I want to show numbers with comma separator, no matter the format of the original data. Is that possible?

*PROC LOGISTIC DATA=BD DESCENDING;*

*MODEL DESFECHO=IDADE /LINK=GLOGIT;*

*RUN;*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Relevant options:

[NLDECSEPARATOR option](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/nlsref/p01itdp4pna998n1wc25iifsephg.htm) - tells SAS to respect the locale when deciding what separator to use

[LOCALE option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_007/nlsref/n1n9bwctsthuqbn1xgipyw5xwujl.htm) - tells SAS what country/etc. you're "in"

[NLNUM format](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/1.0/nlsref/n15n1e10clx3qpn1vrnd0awyhd2s.htm) - one format that tells SAS to respect the locale

Different combinations of these will work... for example, this works:

```
options locale="FR_FR";
options NLDECSEPARATOR ;
data test;
  x = 3.5;
  output;
run;

proc print data=test;
run;
```

As does this:

```
options locale="FR_FR";

data test;
  x = 3.5;
  format x nlnum6.2;
  output;
run;

proc print data=test;
run;
```

The key is the locale (which may well be already set at startup), and then one of the other options to tell SAS you care about the decimal.

Comment: I used the 1st option and it worked! thank you!